# Versioned Docusaurus site returns 404 for the other languages

Tags: docusaurus

I receive the following error message when I want to navigate to a translated page of a versioned Docusaurus site:

> Cannot GET /docs/de/...

I followed all the recommendations there are to find on the docs site. Here is what I have.

Crowdin.yaml:

```
files:
  -
    source: '/docs/**/*.md'
    translation: '/website/translated_docs/%locale%/**/%original_file_name%'    
    languages_mapping: &anchor
      locale:
        'de': 'de'
  -
    source: '/website/i18n/en.json'
    translation: '/website/i18n/%locale%.json'
    languages_mapping: *anchor

  -
    source: '/website/versioned_docs/**/*.md'
    translation: '/website/translated_docs/%locale%/**/%original_file_name%'
    languages_mapping: *anchor
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "examples": "docusaurus-examples",
    "start": "docusaurus-start",
    "build": "docusaurus-build",
    "publish-gh-pages": "docusaurus-publish",
    "write-translations": "docusaurus-write-translations",
    "version": "docusaurus-version",
    "rename-version": "docusaurus-rename-version",
    "crowdin-upload": "crowdin --config ../crowdin.yaml upload sources --auto-update -b master",
    "crowdin-download": "crowdin --config ../crowdin.yaml download -b master",
    "lint": "yarn run markdownlint --config .markdownlint.json ../docs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "docusaurus": "1.13.0",
    "markdownlint-cli": "^0.18.0"
  }
}
```

versions.json

```
[
    "2019.6.0",
    "2019.5.0"
]
```

languages.js

```js
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2017-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

const languages = [
  {
    enabled: true,
    name: "English",
    tag: "en"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "日本語",
    tag: "ja"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "العربية",
    tag: "ar"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Bosanski",
    tag: "bs-BA"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Català",
    tag: "ca"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Čeština",
    tag: "cs"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Dansk",
    tag: "da"
  },
  {
    enabled: true,
    name: "Deutsch",
    tag: "de"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Ελληνικά",
    tag: "el"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Español",
    tag: "es-ES"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "فارسی",
    tag: "fa-IR"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Suomi",
    tag: "fi"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Français",
    tag: "fr"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "עִברִית",
    tag: "he"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Magyar",
    tag: "hu"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Bahasa Indonesia",
    tag: "id-ID"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Italiano",
    tag: "it"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Afrikaans",
    tag: "af"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "한국어",
    tag: "ko"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "मराठी",
    tag: "mr-IN"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Nederlands",
    tag: "nl"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Norsk",
    tag: "no-NO"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Polskie",
    tag: "pl"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Português",
    tag: "pt-PT"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Português (Brasil)",
    tag: "pt-BR"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Română",
    tag: "ro"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Русский",
    tag: "ru"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Slovenský",
    tag: "sk-SK"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Српски језик (Ћирилица)",
    tag: "sr"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Svenska",
    tag: "sv-SE"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Türkçe",
    tag: "tr"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Українська",
    tag: "uk"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "Tiếng Việt",
    tag: "vi"
  },
  {
    enabled: false,
    name: "中文",
    tag: "zh-CN"
  },
  { enabled: false, name: "繁體中文", tag: "zh-TW" }
];
module.exports = languages;
```

The directory structure:

```
.
D:\Source\dime-scheduler-docs
.
+---docs
|   +---administrator-manual
|   |   +---administration
|   |   |   +---administration-identity.md
|   |   |   +---administration-roles.md
|   |   |   +---administration-usergroups.md
|   |   |   +---administration-users-generatedcontent.md
|   |   |   \---administration-users.md
|   |   +---fasttrack
|   |   +---settings
|   |   +---troubleshooting
|   |   +---configuration.md
|   +---developer-manual
|   +---faq
|   +---guides
|   +---installation-manual
|   +---intro
|   +---plugins
|   +---user-manual
+---website
|   +---blog
|   +---core
|   +---i18n
|   |   +---de.json
|   |   \---en.json
|   +---pages
|   |   +---de
|   |   |   +---index.js
|   |   |   \---versions.js
|   |   \---en
|   |       +---index.js
|   |       \---versions.js
|   +---static
|   |   +---css
|   |   +---fonts
|   |   +---img
|   |   \---js
|   +---translated_docs
|   |   \---de
|   |       +---user-manual
|   |       |   +---authentication
|   |       |   |   +---authentication-intro.md
|   |       +---version-2019.5.0
|   |       |   +---administrator-manual
|   |       |   |   +---administration
|   |       |   |   |   +---administration-identity.md|   |       
|   |       \---version-2019.6.0
|   |           +---installation-manual
|   |           |   +---backoffice
|   |           |   |   \---install-backoffice-service.md
|   |           |   +---dynamics
|   |           +---plugins           
|   |           \---user-manual
|   +---versioned_docs
|   |   +---version-2019.5.0
|   |   +---version-2019.6.0
|   +---versioned_sidebars
|   |   \---version-2019.5.0-sidebars.json
|   +---.markdownlint.json
|   +---languages.js
|   +---main.js
|   +---package.json
|   +---sidebars.json
|   +---siteConfig.js
|   +---versions.json
|   \---yarn.lock
+---.dockerignore
+---.gitignore
+---azure-pipelines.yml
+---crowdin.yaml
+---docker-compose.yml
+---Dockerfile
+---README.md
+---tree.txt
\---yarn.lock
```

After running the commands `yarn crowdin-upload` and `yarn crowdin-download`, the `translated_docs` folder is populated. Inside the `de` subfolder, there are the folders of the docs, including another subdirectory for the version `version-2019.6.0`.

When I run `yarn start` and switch the language to the other language, the top menu is translated. However, when I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/docs/de/user-manual/user-intro`, I get a blank page with the error message "Cannot GET/...".

When I remove the versions.json and versions.js from the project, everything works perfectly. Furthermore, if I keep the versioning and navivate to the 'next' version, it's also working fine.

So the issue must be located somewhere in this area. As far as I know, there is no way of debugging or diagnosing the exact problem. Which is why I would like to hear who else has had this problem?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible repo ? How about your `languages.js` ? Can you copy paste your final directory structure

Comment: @Endi I updated the question. I could provide you with a reproducible repo but then we'd have to take this private.

Comment: Did you try building the static html ? Does it work ? I'm suspecting it only work on prod

Comment: I tried what you suggested. It doesn't throw any errors anymore but the contents are not translated, apart from the top menu and the collapsible navigation groups. Everything else remains in English.

Comment: What's the crowdin project ? If its not yet translated in crowdin, of course it will remains in English